# How can I stop Substance's runtime texture caching?

Tags: unity, textures, performance, procedural-generation, substance-engine

Procedural textures with the [Substance Engine](https://www.allegorithmic.com/substance-unity) seem to update very quickly if you turn off caching, modify one exposed variable at a time, modify it frequently, and even then only after you've attempted to modify it 2 or 3 times.

However, I want basically the opposite. For example, units have a "blood" variable that generates blood differently on them as they take damage, as well as a "battle wear" variable that generates scratches and dents, but doesn't revert when they heal.

So to force a variable not to cache, I have to set it to some dummy value, then back to normal, then call `RebuildTexturesImmediately`.

How can I tell Substance not to cache a variable at runtime, so I can change it once and have the texture regenerate quickly?

Comment: Could you a bit of relevant code?

Comment: I get a 404 error when I click the link. I'd guess that the url is outdated. Perhaps [this](https://www.allegorithmic.com/substance-unity) is a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [CacheProceduralProperty](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ProceduralMaterial.CacheProceduralProperty.html) to specify at runtime what properties you want to cache and which ones you don't.